# Should I use joins for this, or would it be better to keep the differences in a column for easier access?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have the tables

```
users
    bigint id
    // More columns ...

matches
    bigint id
    // More columns ...

participants
    bigint id
    bigint user_id references users
    bigint match_id references matches
    bigint opponent_id references participants
    int stat1
    int stat2
    // More stat columns ...
    string nonStat1
    string nonStat2
    // More non stat columns ...
```

Each match is a collection of 1v1 matches between participants. What we would like to know is: For a given user, what are their average stat differences were compared to their opponent by some kind of match filter (for example, only for matches which took place after 8pm local time). So, `AVG(a.stat1 - b.stat1), AVG(a.stat2 - b.stat2), ...`.

I haven't worked out how the query would look if there were no columns that stored the computed result of `a.stat1 - b.stat1, ...` whenever a relevant row was affected, but I assume it's doable with joins.

Because this table will get decently large, on the order of nearly 1B rows (with old rows being deleted once they are more than 6 months old), would it make sense to have columns such as

```
participants
    // ...
    int stat1_opponent_diff
    int stat2_opponent_diff
    // ...
```

Since that makes the queries beyond simple to write, or should the diffs be left out of the table? I could move the matchups out to their own table, such as

```
matchups
    bigint id
    bigint participant1_id references participants
    bigint participant2_id references participants

participants
    bigint id
    bigint user_id references users
    bigint match_id references matches
    bigint team_id references teams
    // More columns ...
```

But I'm not sure if that makes sense given the use case. With `opponent_id` and the stats diff columns in the participants table, it's been ridiculously easy to run queries, but I don't know enough to know if it's a bad idea to store the diffs as columns, since it smells like derived columns, which as far as I know are a bad thing?

Comment: In general you should not store redundant information like this, unless there's no other way to get acceptable query performance.

Comment: In a 1v1 scenario, I cannot really see the point of the participants table. matches can store both players

Comment: The structure seems to be wrong. I cannot imagine the constraint which forbids the situation when opponents are not synchronized (for example, triple-user ring of opponents may be easily created, i.e. id=1 has opponent_id=2, id=2 has opponent_id=3, id=3 has opponent_id=1). I'd recommend separate relation table which checks this constraint strongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I would store the *differences*.  After all, someone might come along and want the ratio of two metrics instead.  Ooops.  Didn't think of that.

You can probably do what you want with the data structure you have.  With the right indexes, there shouldn't be a problem.  The queries would be structured as:

```
select avg(p.stat1 - p2.stat1), . . .
from matches m join
     participants p
     on p.match_id = m.match_id and
        p.user_id = ? join
     participants p2
     on p2.match_id = m.match_id and
        p2.user_id <> ?
where . . .;
```

You want indexes on:

- `participants(user_id, match_id)`
- `matches(match_id)`  -- probably the primary key anyway
- `participants(match_id, user_id)`.

The two indexes on `participants` are used for the two different `join`s.  The first is used to filter the matches by `user_id`.  The second is to get to the second participant.

Comment: Yea that's what I had been leaning towards, the idea of storing the differences left a bad taste in my mouth. Thanks!!